# Removing branch mapping in Team Foundation Server 2010

Tags: .net, version-control, tfs

I've got a solution in source control with multiple projects.  When I first migrated old code to TFS, I created main, dev, release areas for branches.  Being new to TFS at the time, I branched a single project to the dev area, which created the little silver branch icon to show the relationship between them.  Having done that, of course, I can no longer branch above or below that spot.  So, I can't branch a whole solution.

I tried removing the mapping/association of branches so that I could branch from higher in the tree, but can't find a way to do that.  I backed up source control and deleted all other associated branches except for the original one in the Main branch, but the association is still there despite having deleted the others (I assume TFS still contains history of those associations to the other branches I created).

My question is:  How do I safely remove branch associations (the silver branch icon) while keeping history if possible (I don't care about being able to merge anymore), so that I can branch from another area higher or lower in the tree?

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Evidently, the right-click menu does not have this option due to user feedback.  It can be accessed via File > Source Control > Branching and Merging > Convert to Folder

Source: [Microsoft Connect](https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/503673/it-should-be-possible-to-change-branch-relationships-in-tfs-after-they-are-created?wa=wsignin1.0#)

Comment: What user feedback? This is quite frustrating ... But thank you for your answer, really helpful!

Comment: Ah, looks like they've taken it down now.  Basically the feedback was that the context menu was too cluttered, so since this option wasn't used very often it was moved up the the main menu and out of the way until needed.  Honestly, I had no idea these options even existed until I read the feedback.  :-/

Comment: This helped a lot. Thanks. @Microsoft: Great user "experience".