# how to delete a branch and branch relationship

Tags: tfs

I have deleted a branch folder for application, but I am unable to remove the relationship and change icon for the folder ?? Why is that ?

[image]

Comment: possible duplicate of [Removing branch mapping in Team Foundation Server 2010](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4500765/removing-branch-mapping-in-team-foundation-server-2010)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Select application-DEV branch in team explorer. Select File menu > source control > Branching and merging > convert to folder.