# Branch deletion in TFS 2010 is not working

Tags: visual-studio-2010, tfs, visual-studio-2013

I know several people has already asked this question but I tried almost every approach and did not help me. I am trying to delete a branch in TFS 2010 and I am unable to do this operation. When I try to checkin my delete operation I get following message

```
 TF14098: Access Denied: User xyz needs Checkin permission(s) for $/Path to branch/*.
```

I remember until few months back, I was able to delete the branch but not it is not working.

I modify the files inside the branch but when I try to rename the branch or try to delete it then I get above error message.

I have tried method proposed in this answer: [Removing branch mapping in Team Foundation Server 2010](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4500765/removing-branch-mapping-in-team-foundation-server-2010)

I would like to add one more thing. If I create branch using visual studio 2010 then I can delete that branch later however if I create branch using visual studio 2013 then I can not delete that branch.

Comment: Try this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9466972/clearing-special-permissions-from-folders-in-a-branch/10600473#10600473 there is probably some folder with a Deny all set somewhere (in my case it was a `Packages` folder for nuget).

Comment: @Dave: Thanks.your suggestion helped me. In my case I was not allowed  to check-in one file and in result, I was unable to check-in delete operation for whole branch.