# How to stop the visual studio 2013 from inheriting team project security settings while creating a branch in TFS

Tags: visual-studio-2010, tfs, visual-studio-2013

I started investigating this [issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26977080/branch-deletion-in-tfs-2010-is-not-working) and realized that visual studio 2013 inherits the team project security setting while creating from team project. It is happening in visual studio only because when I try to use visual stuido 2010 then branch does not inherit the security setting. Is there a way to force visual studio 2013 to stop inheriting the security settings from team project.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To stop inheriting security settings you need to open the folder you want in Web Access. For that folder select "> | Security" and change the Inheritance settings.

[image]

Comment: what do you mean by "open folder you want in Web Access"? Please explain it little bit more. Thanks

Comment: Just noticed that you have TFS2010. 1) Upgrade your TFS. 2) You can do the same in TFS 2010 by Right-clicking on the folder and selecting security in the Server Explorer.